# else if statements not firing beyond first iteration

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I am trying to use if and else statements to display pictures based upon the season.
For  `var currentMonth = new Date().getMonth();` it returns the current month as 0-11 0 being Jan and 11 being Dec.  Now I am fairly sure that my problem lays within how I am executing the else if statements.  When I change my desktop date it will only display the image for winter or for spring no matter the month I use.  It displays the winter picture when it should but the spring image will display during all other months.  That says to me that its an issue with the else if statements.  Any help would be much appreciated

```
<script language="javascript">

  function retrievePictures(){
    var currentMonth = new Date().getMonth();


    if(currentMonth >= 10 || currentMonth <=1){
      //winter
      var html = '<img src="img/hall-of-gods.jpg" width="600" height="400" alt="Hall Of The Gods" />';

    }

    else if(currentMonth >= 2 || currentMonth <=4){
      //spring
      var html = '<img src="img/merlyn.jpg" width="600" height="400" alt="Spring Time Cat" />';

    }

    else if(currentMonth >= 5 || currentMonth <=7){
      //summer    
      var html = '<img src="img/bounty.jpg" alt="Summer Bounty" width="600" height="400" />';

    }

    else{
      //autum    
      var html = '<img src="img/louis.jpg" alt="King Louis" width="600" height="400" />';

    }
    document.write(html);
  }
</script>



<div class="slideshow">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    retrievePictures();
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any iterations. Did you want to surround this with a `while` loop?

Comment: You probably want an and instead of or in some of your conditions.

Comment: Ok, let me see how that works out.

Comment: @user3151902 I was unsure of the proper term for what I am doing here so I used the iteration.  What might be a more proper name to call running through and executingh else if statements.

Comment: Use && with || morethan one else if conditions may satisfies...

Comment: @TZHX Bingo, that was the problem, thank you much!  It appears Manoj Yadav posted a fixed chunk of code for it as well... Again many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `switch case` instead of a lot of `if else`.
The syntax is more clear to understand. Also instead of declaring 4 times on the variable html you can declare it only once before the switch statement.

```
var currentMonth = new Date().getMonth();
var html ='';
switch (currentMonth) {
    case 10:
    case 11:
    case 0:
        //winter
      html = '<img src="img/hall-of-gods.jpg" width="600" height="400" alt="Hall Of The Gods" />';
   break;

    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    //spring
        html = '<img src="img/merlyn.jpg" width="600" height="400" alt="Spring Time Cat" />';
        break;
    case 5:
    case 6:
    case 7:
//summer 
        html = '<img src="img/bounty.jpg" alt="Summer Bounty" width="600" height="400" />';
        break;
    case 8:
    case 9:
      //autum 
         html = '<img src="img/louis.jpg" alt="King Louis" width="600" height="400" />';
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change to below code should solve your problem.
I have made  `||` as `&&` and `<=` replaced with `< num+1`

```
function retrievePictures(){
    var currentMonth = new Date().getMonth();


    if(currentMonth > 9 || currentMonth <2){
    //winter
        var html = '<img src="img/hall-of-gods.jpg" width="600" height="400" alt="Hall Of The Gods" />';

    }

  else if(currentMonth > 1 && currentMonth < 5){
    //spring
        var html = '<img src="img/merlyn.jpg" width="600" height="400" alt="Spring Time Cat" />';

    }

    else if(currentMonth > 4 && currentMonth < 8){
    //summer    
        var html = '<img src="img/bounty.jpg" alt="Summer Bounty" width="600" height="400" />';

    }

 else{
    //autum    
        var html = '<img src="img/louis.jpg" alt="King Louis" width="600" height="400" />';

    }
        document.write(html);
    }
    </script>



    <div class="slideshow">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            retrievePictures();
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problems seems to be that if you check that you need AND operator when you have following numbers.

In your if statements you checked `currentMonth >= 2` since 2,..,11 is bigger than 2 your if statements stops and doesn't check the rest after this. It only showed winter because it was above this if statement.

```
function retrievePictures(){
    var currentMonth = new Date().getMonth();

    if(currentMonth >= 10 || currentMonth <= 1){
        //winter 10,11 || 0,1
        var html = '<img src="img/hall-of-gods.jpg" width="600" height="400" alt="Hall Of The Gods" />';
    }
    else if(currentMonth >= 2 && currentMonth <= 4){
        //spring 2,3,4
        var html = '<img src="img/merlyn.jpg" width="600" height="400" alt="Spring Time Cat" />';
    }
    else if(currentMonth >= 5 && currentMonth <= 7){
        //summer 5,6,7
        var html = '<img src="img/bounty.jpg" alt="Summer Bounty" width="600" height="400" />';
    }
    else{
        //autum 8,9
        var html = '<img src="img/louis.jpg" alt="King Louis" width="600" height="400" />';
    }
    document.write(html);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like others have mentioned, the error comes from using OR (`||`) instead of AND (`&&`) in your if statements. If I may, I'd propose not to use any if, instead create an array with the data and retrieve the img's src and alt from it:

```js
function retrievePictures() {
 let t = [
 {months: [0,1,10,11], img: {src: 'hall-of-gods.jpg', alt:'Hall Of The Gods'}},
   {months: [2,3,4], img: {src: 'merlyn.jpg', alt:'Spring Time Cat'}},
   {months: [5,6,7], img: {src: 'bounty.jpg', alt:'Summer Bounty'}},
   {months: [8,9], img: {src: 'louis.jpg', alt:'King Louis'}}
 ];
  let currentMonth = new Date().getMonth();
  let obj = t.find(e => e.months.includes(currentMonth));
  return `<img src='${obj.img.src}' alt='${obj.img.alt}' width="600" height="400" />`;
}

document.write(retrievePictures())
```

Comment: I like this approach.  I think I am going to go with an array instead of the if statements.  so In the line   'let obj = t.find(e => e.months.includes(currentMonth));' is the e before => defined by 'e.months.includes(currentMonth));'?

Comment: @LeoFrost `e` is the function parameter, it holds the iterated value. The line could be rewritten to `let obj = t.find(function(e) {return e.months.includes(currentMont); });`